# Flask - How to access remember_me token in all subdomains

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am trying to create an app using `Flask` with more than 9 controllers, some of them are in a different subdomains.

I am using **Flask_Login** to allow users to login, the users controller exist in a separated subdomain, the problem happens if i visited that subdomain, inside my console it shows a redirect to login the user first to access that subdomain, and inside cookies i can't see the remember_me token.

Here are the configurations for the extension:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'localhost:5000'

# Login configurations
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION = timedelta(seconds=7*24*60*60)
REMEMBER_COOKIE_NAME = 'myapp.remember'
REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost:5000'

from .controllers.client import client_route

app.register_blueprint(client_route, subdomain='client')
```

The domain inside cookies is **localhost**, how can i change it to something like **.localhost** ??

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Visiting the subdomain inside console?"

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, thanks for your interest :), i mean inside python interpreter if i visited the **client.localhost:5000** after authorization it shows me 302 redirect code! in fact, i am already logged in!!

Comment: Can u get the cookie on the main domain (`localhost:5000`)?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, the cookie showing just localhost!!

Comment: So it's not working on the main domain either?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, correct, i am trying to make it something like **.localhost**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE` in your config to `False`

According to [Flask-Login's documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cookie-settings):

> Restricts the “Remember Me” cookie’s scope to secure channels
>   (typically HTTPS).

It only sets the cookie on HTTPS version of your application

Comment: I've changed the value , the post request sending with CSRFToken, but the response shows different error, now it says `The CSRF session token is missing`, even if i sent the csrf_token with the request!!

Comment: Well, that is another problem which seems it is not related to Flask-Login

Comment: Try to set it as `None`